# Equivalent to Ruby's ensure or Java's finally in shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, try-catch-finally

I am pretty sure the answer to my question is No, but I am seeking confirmation.

In Ruby, the following block:

```
begin
  foo
rescue
  bar
ensure
  baz
end
```

will start executing `foo`, and, if any errors are raised, it will stop doing `foo` and begin doing `bar` instead.

The `ensure` block is code that will be run last, *regardless* whether there are any errors during `foo`.

Java has the same structure, but the keywords are `try`, `catch`, and `finally`.

This is the part I want to accomplish in a bash script: I want a snippet of code which will be run either at the very end of my script, or immediately after an error is raised and the script wants to exit.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- `fo` is a bash function that returns `0` on success
- `bar` and `baz` are bash functions

The following should behave according to your expectations:

```
foo
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    bar
fi
baz
```

A shorter version:

```
if ! foo; then
    bar
fi
baz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install a trap handler which will run on exit, whether that's from an explicit `exit` command or from reaching the end of the script.

```
trap 'echo script exiting with exit code $?' EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash has a number of fake signals:

`EXIT`code is executed on exit from the script

`RETURN`code is executed on a call to `return` (usually in a function)

`DEBUG`code is executed at each statement

`ERR`code is executed on error (conditionals are a special case)

You can set a `trap` handler on error with the ERR fake signal.  For example:

```
foo() {
    echo "Executing foo"
    return 1    # non-zero is a failure
}

bar() {
    echo "Executing bar"
}

baz() {
    echo "Executing baz"
} 

trap 'bar' ERR
foo

# Reset trap
trap - ERR
baz
```

Gives:

```
Executing foo
Executing bar
Executing baz
```

If `foo` is altered to return zero:

```
Executing foo
Executing baz
```

Functions do not normally inherit the `ERR` trap, but see `set -E`.